# I'm trying to create a Java program to create and write a text file, but

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File newTxt = new File("C:/Users/cauan/Desktop/newTxt.txt");

    if(newTxt.exists()) System.out.println("The file already exists!");
    else {
        try{ 
            newTxt.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(newTxt);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            bw.write("This is my Prog");
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }        
}
```

This is my code.... But i dunno why am i getting an error :/

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't get an error when I run your program.  Please [edit] your question to include the *full text* of the error your are getting, including any stack trace being generated.

Comment: "I'm trying to create a Java program to create and write a text file, but" But what? The suspense is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the BufferedWriter and FileWriter in order to save the contents of the file.

```
bw.close();
fw.close();
```

[Complete program link](http://ideone.com/xpBHy7)